# Direction flag usage in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have read in my book that when the `SI` register is less than the `DI` register (in string manipulation), then the direction flag equals 0 else the direction flag equals 1.

But I have also read that instructions normally don't change the direction flag, so what is the exact usage of it? Should we set or unset this flag depending on our strings first and last index? (Should **we** handle this flag or let the CPU handle it?)

Am I wrong in above statements?

Comment: That's not how it works. It has nothing do with whether `SI` is less than `DI` or not. It only has to do with whether you want them to increment or decrement when using string instructions.

Comment: ok so what about the other part of the question we should set it always or CPU handle it?

Comment: Look at the Operation section of [`movsb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html) or [`rep movsb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz) for example: they only read DF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPU never automatically sets or clears the direction flag. That is only done by software.

The CPU uses the direction flag when executing string instructions to determine whether to increment or decrement `SI` and `DI`.

Normally `DF` is left clear all the time. Software should set `DF` before using a string instruction for which `SI` and `DI` should be decremented.

One reason that you may want `SI` and `DI` to be decremented is when performing a memory copy where the buffers overlap and the source address is less than the destination address. In this case, a normal forward copy will overwrite part of the source buffer before it has been read, while a reverse copy will work.

A reverse copy requires `(DS:)SI` and `ES:DI` pointers initially point to the highest element to be moved, instead of the lowest.  (Still the first byte to be copied.)

---

On current Intel CPUs (Skylake for example) backwards `std`/`rep movsb` is *much* slower than forward copy.  Optimized microcode that copies in 16 or 32 byte chunks only activates for the `cld` / DF=0 forward-copy case.

For example, a 1000000 iteration repeat-loop around a 4096 byte `rep movsb` with aligned source and destination took a total of ~42 ms forward, or ~1000ms backwards, on an i7-6700k Skylake at about 4.1GHz in long mode.  Performance in real mode should be similar.

`repe/ne cmpsb` or `repe/ne scasb` are always slow (just 1 byte at a time), and probably not slower with DF=1 vs. DF=0.  Only `rep movs` and `rep stos` have optimized microcode.

On early x86 CPUs like original 8086 through 286, all `rep`-string instructions had the advantage of small code size and not requiring instruction fetch while loading/storing data.  And there weren't SIMD vector instructions you could use instead to go much faster.